# Blank title in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titlebar

Is it possible to remove title bar which I think is ugly and doesn't fit in my application but still use actionbar? After I call

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE | Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

the title bar stays but piece of my view is gone(cant scroll up)[image: view of app]

Is it possible to get rid of title bar but still keep actionbar, if I dont request it as window feature getActionBar() returns null everytime..

Comment: What? I want only action bar without title bar!

Comment: @Ruuhkis  `ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` try this it will help you remove logo and icon from action bar

Comment: @NobuGames the circle was showing that the scrollbar was as up as it could go and you can see part of first soundview is gone which is because of the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE | Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); Didn't know actionbar were part of titlebar

Comment: @Ruuhkis ur most welcome

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Following Honeycomb, Action Bar was introduced to provide more functionalities, Well you can hide logo and title from it using this

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```