# Holo.NoTitleBar & NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, swipe

I have android application with 3.0 and an activity with tab and swipe. I want to remove the title bar, but when write `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`, and run my application, the log cat says one NullPointerException check me, and when i remove this line, the application run very well.

This is my code:

> public class Estructura extends FragmentActivity implements
>           ActionBar.TabListener {

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the three primary sections of the app. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} that will display the
 * object collection.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_estructura);

    // Create an adapter that when requested, will return a fragment
    // representing an object in
    // the collection.
    //
    // ViewPager and its adapters use support library fragments, so we must
    // use
    // getSupportFragmentManager.
    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is
    // no hierarchical
    // parent.
    // actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener
    // for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between different app sections, select
                    // the corresponding tab.
                    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if
                    // we have a reference to the
                    // Tab.
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the
        // TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the primary sections of the app.
 */
public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 6; // number of tabs

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String tabLabel = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.inicio);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.fotos);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.videos);
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.visitas);
            break;
        case 4:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.cursos);
            break;
        case 5:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.contacto);
            break;
        }

        return tabLabel;
    }
}

/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    // @Override
    // public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
    // container,
    // Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //
    // Bundle args = getArguments();
    // int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
    //
    // int tabLayout = 0;
    // switch (position) {
    // case 0:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
    // break;
    // case 1:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
    // break;
    // case 2:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
    // break;
    // case 3:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab4;
    // break;
    // case 4:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab5;
    // break;
    // case 5:
    // tabLayout = R.layout.tab6;
    // break;
    // }
    //
    // View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);
    //
    // return rootView;
    // }
}
```

}

and the log cat:

> 06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lirioandroid.museocaldemoron/com.lirioandroid.museocaldemoron.Estructura}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:229)
>   06-14 12:31:55.960: E/AndroidRuntime(21882):    at com.lirioandroid.museocaldemoron.Estructura.onCreate(Estructura.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

See your code at com.lirioandroid.museocaldemoron.Estructura.onCreate(Estructura.java:35), I assume it's anything that touches the actionBar variable here:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

When you set noTitleBar, that actionBar doesn't exist anymore!  You might want to try [Blank title in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493589/blank-title-in-action-bar)