# Blank title in action bar android API 10

Tags: android

I used to read this topic [Blank title in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493589/blank-title-in-action-bar?answertab=votes#tab-top)
However, my problem is I create application with API 10 and it doesn't support **android.app.ActionBar**. 
Any ideas for me to make a blank title in `ActionBar` API 10. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: if  can't use that method means, Um, have you tried setTitle("") ?

Comment: @Phan If you think it's correct answer, you should mark it as correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this??

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actionbar are supported from API 11. i.e from Honeycomb. If you want to support below API 11. You should go for Support library.

Check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionBar` APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

and follow this official [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding)

or else you can also use [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)